# When running my code sometimes steps are ignored, why is this happening? Java

Tags: java, netbeans

So I made a Pong game in java and for some reason sometimes the ball doesn't check the collision with the bottom or the top of the screen. What can I do to fix this?

this piece is the collision checking with the bottom or the top of the screen:

```
if(y-20<0 && dir == UP_RIGHT)
    dir=DOWN_RIGHT;
else if (y-20<0 && dir == UP_LEFT)
    dir=DOWN_LEFT;
//Down
if(y+20>500 && dir == DOWN_RIGHT)
    dir=UP_RIGHT;
else if(y+20>500 && dir == DOWN_LEFT)
    dir=UP_LEFT;`
```

The ball collision system:

```
 public void Blogic(Random random,HumanPaddle p1, HumanPaddle p2)
 {//collision
    //Left
    if(x<=50)
    {
        if(y>= p1.y && y<=p1.y + 80)
           RandomDir(6,4,random);
    }

    //Right
    else if(x>=650)
    {
        if(y>=p2.y && y<=p2.y+ 80)
           RandomDir(3,1,random);
    }
     //Up
    if(y-20<0 && dir == UP_RIGHT)
        dir=DOWN_RIGHT;
    else if (y-20<0 && dir == UP_LEFT)
        dir=DOWN_LEFT;
    //Down
    if(y+20>500 && dir == DOWN_RIGHT)
        dir=UP_RIGHT;
    else if(y+20>500 && dir == DOWN_LEFT)
        dir=UP_LEFT;
}
```

The ball movement system:

```
public void move()
{
    switch(dir)
    {
        case STOP: 
            xVel *=0; yVel *=0; 
            break;
        case LEFT: 
            xVel--; 
            break;
        case UP_LEFT: 
            xVel--; 
            yVel--; 
            break;
        case DOWN_LEFT: 
            xVel--; 
            yVel++; 
            break;
        case RIGHT: 
            xVel++; 
            break;
        case UP_RIGHT: 
            xVel++; 
            yVel--; 
            break;
        case DOWN_RIGHT:
            xVel++; 
            yVel++; 
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
    // Velocity settings
    if (xVel>=3) 
        xVel=3;
    else if (xVel <=-3) 
        xVel=-3;
    if(yVel >=3) 
        yVel=3;
    else if(yVel<=-3) 
        yVel=-3;       

    x += xVel; 
    y += yVel;
}
```

Run:

```
public void run() 
{
    for (;;)
    {
        p1.move();
        p2.move();
        ball.move();
        ball.Blogic(rand, p1, p2);
        Score();
        repaint();
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Tennis.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a hint: always put down braces{} even for one statement if/else branches. And then method names go camelCase.. Deviating from such standards makes your code harder to read for experienced Java folks. Finally.. What now - java or Javascript?

Comment: @GhostCat Or use the code formatter in your IDE, then you don't need to put in redundant { } ;)

Comment: Code formatters don't really help with subtle bugs that omitting those braces cause sooner or later. Most often sooner.

Comment: hmmm while I don't know what are `p1` and `p2`, I don't see problems with the code you posted, could be in another code

Comment: wait, on collision you're just changing direction, `move` will decrease the velocity after collision but what if it didn't decrease it "enough" and so your ball continues through the screen, In my opinion you could on collision make velocity zero and `move` will increase it thus moving the ball into the direction you want

Comment: this may not be realistic though

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time seeing exactly how the collision works without the visual but I would try without the extra checking on the direction for the up and bottom boards. I believe that by doing this you are checking for something that should ways be true anyways so it is simply too strict.

Remove: "&& dir == UP_RIGHT" and the contrary.
For some reason, this might not be true and completely skip over the check.

Answer (score 0):

I made this changes inside that piece and now it is working fine.

```
if(y <=10)
    {
       if(dir == UP_RIGHT) dir=DOWN_RIGHT;
       else if (dir == UP_LEFT)dir = DOWN_LEFT;
       else yVel=-yVel;
    }

    //Down
    if(y>=490)
    {
        if(dir == DOWN_RIGHT)dir=UP_RIGHT;
        else if (dir ==DOWN_LEFT) dir=UP_LEFT;
        else yVel=-yVel;
    }
```